# Application is not running on device when using swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

The error coming while build the application with this

> "ld: file too small (length=0) file
>   '/Users/harjitsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MKSwiftBasic-beooqvoqmmdzlqffdydibcpuweln/Build/Intermediates/MKSwiftBasic.build/Debug-iphoneos/MKSwiftBasic.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewController.o'
>   for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: try to clean and build the project ...or restart it

Comment: which tutorial is best for fast learning of swift in iOS ?

Comment: I think you should use `ray wanderlich` tutorials....but there are many more....just google it ....